# Jlink spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jlink

I have a simple hello world spring 2 boot app, which runs with full JDK 13. Now I am trying to get this to run with a custom JRE using spring boot.

In past when I have need external jars, I have run `jdeps -s json-20190722.jar` to see what modules I need.

```
$jdeps -s json-20190722.jar 
json-20190722.jar -> java.base
```

But when I do this with Spring I get

```
$jdeps -s spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar -> java.base
spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar -> java.desktop
spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar -> java.logging
spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar -> java.management
spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar -> java.naming
spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar -> java.sql
spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar -> java.xml
spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar -> not found
```

It also fails when I do

```
$ jdeps --generate-module-info . spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar | more
Missing dependence: ./spring.boot/module-info.java not generated
Error: missing dependencies
spring.boot
   org.springframework.boot.Banner                    -> org.springframework.core.env.Environment           not found
   org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader      -> groovy.lang.Closure                                not found
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try adding a modulepath?

Answer (score 7):

You need also all your dependencies and point it in class path option.

```
$jdeps -R -s --multi-release 13 -cp 'path-to-dependencies/*' your-app.jar
```

You can find all dependencies if you extract your fat jar (see [The Executable Jar File Structure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html#executable-jar-jar-file-structure.)):

```
 jar -xvf your-jar-file.jar
```

Or retrieve them with Gradle and custom task:

```
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.default
    into 'build/libs/dependencies'
}
```